# HotTowel: breeze.angular.js file missing

Tags: angularjs, breeze, hottowel

I am following John Papa's course [Building Apps with Angular and Breeze - Part 1] on Plural Sight to build Breeze-Angular SPA.

I have included all references in index.html according to video.

```
<script src="../Scripts/breeze.debug.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/breeze.angular.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/breeze.directives.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/breeze.saveErrorExtensions.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/breeze.to$q.shim.js"></script>
```

I am getting this error :
"GET http://localhost:1930/Scripts/breeze.angular.js"

When I see scripts folder, I cannot find breeze.angular.js file there.
[image]

I have tried updating and re-installing "HotTowel.Angular, HotTowel.Angular.Breeze, Breeze.Angular, Breeze.Angular.Directives" but no success.

Any suggestion where i can find this file?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Found it at http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/breeze-angular

Comment: "breeze.angular.js" has been renamed as "breeze.bridge.angular.js" in January 2015

Comment: Please mark this question as answered when you have a moment ... so we don't think it remains outstanding. Thanks for using Breeze

Comment: @Ward I could not found how to mark my own question as "Answered" neither able to answer my own question :-( Can you please help?

Comment: Add an answer that describes your findings. Come back a few days and select it as the answer.  But only if you can. I don't want to drive you crazy. Better that you're having a good time with Breeze :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"breeze.angular.js" has been renamed to "breeze.bridge.angular.js". Adding reference of "breeze.bridge.angular.js" in index.html resolved it for me.
For more information, visit http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/breeze-angular